# Private Key authentication failed error in Eclipse for openshift

Tags: java, eclipse, git, openshift

In Eclipse, when I am trying to import the existing application from openshift, it gives me following error -

Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.

I have followed the below steps-
1. In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection -> SSH2 -> Key Management
2. Generate RSA Key
3. Paste the public key content in openshift Express account.
4. Save the private key with passphrase.

Even after following above steps I am getting error while cloning the GIT repo.

I have following error in Eclipse log file -

```
!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.ui 4 0 2012-03-21 10:43:20.161
!MESSAGE Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://7261e534e25842aaa353878a6c9af7cf@astofa-astofa.rhcloud.com/~/git/astofa.git/: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.common.ui 4 0 2012-03-21 10:44:21.838
!MESSAGE Operation did not complete in a reasonnable amount of time
```

It says operation did not complete within time however my net connection is working absolutly fine.

Do I need some other tools as well to proceed ? I am new to openshift so I do not have much idea. I was following steps mentioned in -
[Setting up openshift project in Eclipse](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/blogs/getting-started-with-the-openshift-eclipse-plug-in-for-java-applications-on-the-cloud#comment-16865)

and got stuck at step - 5.

Kindly let me know the solution to the issue.

I installed OpenSSH and generated the key pair and that error has gone now. However, a new error has started coming -

An exception occurred while creating local git repository.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

This is something related to GIT.

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you create keys with the eclipse ssh preferences your key will have the wrong permissions. It is created in way that makes it readable/writable by your group of users (on linux/mac: 660) which is usually not accepted by the ssh-subsystem. In these cases it is sufficient to correct the permissions to make the key readable for you only (on linux/mac: 600).

If this does not help to solve your problem, then we'll need to further investigate your issue, I'd need some more details about your setup:

- OS?
- Are you using external ssh executables (environment variable GIT_SSH is set)?
- Do you have some ssh configuration (/.ssh/config)? Is your key listed as "IdentityFile"
- can you cross check your key using command-line git? EGit?
- I bet you added your key to OpenShift in the OpenShift Web-UI?

Comment: I have the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349162/not-able-to-import-openshift-application-in-eclipse please see.