# Not able to import openshift application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, jboss, openshift

I am using eclipse to connect with openshift.

Below are the steps that I have taken.

- sign up in openshift
- created a "JBOSS Application Server 7" application
- downloaded Eclipse Mars
- downloaded openshift tools from the eclipse marketplace
- from options selected import and choose openshift
- sign in to openshift from the prompt(with default server location)
- choose "Use my existing openshift application" and from the browse tab selected that application which I created in openshift & clicked next
- selected "create a new project" in the next window and clicked "Next"
- in "Cloning setting" browse to the location where I want to clone my application
- in the same tab clicked on "SSH Keys wizards" and created a new SSH key.
- in SSH2 preferences checked that my new key is present or not.(it was present).
- clicked finish

it displays cloning from `ssh://<url>`

and then displayed

```
Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
 Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.
ssh://56fdfdad2d5271507d000049@btech-jmi.rhcloud.com/~/git/btech.git/: Connection timed out: connect
```

I have used this steps with several other ecplise versions i.e. mars, indigo, luna, helio (none of them worked).
I used above steps in all of them.

To see if public keys are uploaded on the remote server that checked and found that the public keys are being uploaded every time on the server.

Really stuck at this point.

I have also googled for other ways to do this, but none of them are working for me, I think I am missing something.

I remember doing the same steps sometimes back and it worked but not working this time.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, the reason for this problem was due port issue. In my university they are using cyberoam and they have blocked some ports which were being used by ssh to fetch data from remote.
I just tried same steps at home and it is working as expected.